# Override less defaults

Tags: less

If I have `LESS='-FRX'` as a default environment variable, how can I, as an exception to the rule, run `less` with only `-R`, ie. override/nullify `-FX`?

Answer (score 7):

The options specified in `LESS` can be overridden by options on the command line. You can't however prevent `less` from using the options in `LESS` that you don't explicitly override without changing this variable.

One way to run `less` with a (temporarily) modified value of `LESS` would be to use

```
LESS= less -R filename
```

This would call `less -R` with an empty value in `LESS`.

Or

```
LESS=-R less filename
```

which would call `less` with `LESS` set to `-R` only.

Comment: Nice! This is quite an acceptable solution!

Comment: @Kusalananda is `-+` a recent feature? - see my answer below

Comment: @laktak It's not a recent feature. The variant of `less` that I've been using (on OpenBSD) has had that since at least 2003.

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined `LESS='-FRX'` you can override/disable the `FX` options with

```
less -+FX
```

This is listed in the less man page:

> The  environment variable is parsed before the command line, so command line options override the LESS environment variable.  If an option appears
> in the LESS variable, it can be reset to its default value on the command line by beginning the command line option with "-+".